# Create a Setter Only in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, getter, getter-setter

When I create a setter such as:

```
var masterFrame: CGRect {
    set {
        _imageView.frame = newValue
        _scrollView.frame = newValue
    }
}
```

It's forcing me to make a getter, which I don't want to do.

Is there any way to create a setter in Swift without a getter?

Comment: Nope - sounds like you'd be better off with a method.

Comment: Hmm I suppose this is the ONE thing I will hate about swift then!

Comment: When do you use write-only properties? I've never had occasion to do so.

Comment: I have a class where you can set it's masterframe, but then it's responsible for managing things that will affect itself (never changing the masterframe since its a composite) and the user should NEVER use the master frame except to set it.

Comment: what's wrong with `setMasterFrame(frame : CGRect)`?

Comment: It's not that there's something wrong, but I would have preferred a setter, but its clear that will be the route I'll have to go

Comment: @BryanChen But `foo.masterFrame = someFrame` would be better, if it were possible that is.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well if I really have to, I would use this.

Swift compiler supports some attributes on getters, so you can use `@available(*, unavailable)`:

```
public subscript(index: Int) -> T {
    @available(*, unavailable)
    get {
        fatalError("You cannot read from this object.")
    }
    set(v) {
    }
}
```

This will clearly deliver your intention to the code users.

Answer (score 15):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html):

> The getter is used to read the value, and the setter is used to write
>   the value. The setter clause is optional, and when only a getter is
>   needed, you can omit both clauses and simply return the requested
>   value directly, as described in Read-Only Computed Properties. **But
>   if you provide a setter clause, you must also provide a getter
>   clause.**

Comment: There HAS to be a way around this. There are MANY cases I want setters without getters...

Comment: @Aggressor the way around is in Eonil answer, using `@available(*, unavailable)`.

Answer (score 13):

Use `didSet` instead:

```
var masterFrame:CGRect {
    didSet {
        _imageView.frame = masterFrame
        _scrollView.frame = masterFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work but could also be confusing / misaligned in terms of API design. It leaves masterFrame public to be read which seems like that's not the goal.

Answer (score 11):

A set only property doesn't sound like it makes a lot of sense. You should probably use a method for that instead.

Or, just make the compiler happy and add a getter that you never call:

```
get {
    return _imageView.frame
}
```

Comment: Thats my current solution but I wish I didn't have too :(

Comment: You could also put a ```didSet``` closure on the imageView's frame that updates the scrollView's frame. Or use AutoLayout with constraints to make them equal.

Comment: Setters are for setting. Property observers are for performing tasks before/after a property is accessed. You should definitely be using `didSet` for what you're trying to do.

Comment: "A set only property doesn't sound like it makes a lot of sense." Example: Set the output of a motor on a robot, for which no feedback hardware exists. You could remember the last set speed, and hope the hardware is honoring it, but it doesn't mean much

Answer (score 10):

To have a "setter-only property", you can just have a simple function that sets the value; for example, if we have a private property called `value`, we can have a setter method called, `configureWithValue(value:String)` that updates the property but doesn't allow outside access to the property:

```
private var value:String

func configureWithValue(value:String) {
  self.value = value
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure. You can just return a nil and make the type optional:

```
var color: MyColorEnum? {
    get { return nil }
    set {
      switch newValue! {
      case .Blue:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
      case .Red:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
      }
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you may use `didSet` to avoid the issue all together:

```
var color: MyColorEnum! {
  didSet {
    switch color {
      case .Blue:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
      case .Red:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is there's nothing stopping someone from setting `nil`, crashing your app (or forcing you to add extra handling for that case).

Answer (score 1):

You can give access modifier to `set` for **property** and on `didSet` you can assign it to `_imageView.frame` & `_scrollView.frame`

```
private(set) var masterFrame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        _imageView.frame = masterFrame
        _scrollView.frame = masterFrame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found one exception where I really like a setter only variable which is when I am passing a closure as the only parameter in a method for the sole purpose of saving it of for later execution.

I implement it as a method as follows:

```
typealias ThemeSetter = () -> ()

class Theme {

    fileprivate var themeSetters:[ThemeSetter] = []

    class var shared: Theme {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = Theme()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
        ...

    func setColor(_ entry:@escaping ThemeSetter) {
        entry()
        themeSetters.append(entry)
    }
}
```

I can then call the method as follows:

```
    Theme.shared.setColor({
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = Theme.shared.gameBarTint
    })
```

But I don't like close paretheses after the close bracket, since I may have many lines in the closure.

So, knowing about Trailing Closures I can just change the code to look like this:

```
    Theme.shared.setColor() {
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = Theme.shared.gameBarTint
    }
```

This is perfectly okay and is the syntax that Apple shows for Trailing Closures.  Since there is only the one parameter and being the minimalist that I am I am tempted to make the code even leaner and reduce it to this:

```
    Theme.shared.setColor {
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = Theme.shared.gameBarTint
    }
```

Which is again how Apple shows to do Trailing Closures; Except, this way is usually used for some sort of Predicate where the closure is used to tell the method how to do a sort or when the closure is used at the end of an asynchronous function call as a completion closure.  What I want is to assign the closure to ... Something.

If I replace the method for setColor with a variable it looks like this:

```
    var setColor:ThemeSetter? {
        didSet {
            if setColor != nil {
                setColor?()
                themeSetters.append(setColor!)
                setColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the call looks like this:

```
    Theme.shared.setColor = {
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = Theme.shared.gameBarTint
    }
```

That equals sign means all the difference to be.  It shows that I am assigning a closure and not running some function that uses the closure, even though it does. :') <- need emoticon here.

Final notes: This really has nothing to do with closures, it just shows how you can make a setter only variable, except that it still it returns a nil.  It is not meant to protect the class from having the user accessing the variable for read like a true setter only would.  Also, forgive the tutorial on Trailing Closures and Singletons.

I may not get enough Up Votes to be the correct answer but why is the correct answer, "No you can't! You must use a method call!". I say, "Ni" to that, who needs all that syntax.  Just use a variable and don't read it back or if you do, don't have it return anything. kind of like Rudolf Adamkovic answer, which got 0 Up Votes.